# Inserting into multiple columns access database

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

Problem I am having is when I want to insert into multiple columns at the same time.

What I had was:
 `AccessDataSource1.InsertCommand = "INSERT INTO [CoursesTaken] (StudentID) VALUES ('" TextBox1.Text + "');";  AccessDataSource1.Insert();AccessDataSource1.DataBind();`

That inserts into one column but when I attempt this: 
            `AccessDataSource1.InsertCommand = "INSERT INTO [CoursesTaken] (StudentID, CourseID) VALUES ('" + TextBox1.Text + "''" + TextBox2.Text + "');";  AccessDataSource1.Insert();AccessDataSource1.DataBind();`

It gives me the error message "Number of query values and destination fields are not the same."

So then I attempted this:

```
   if (e.CommandName.CompareTo("Insert") == 0)
    {
        int newIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

        AccessDataSource1.InsertCommand = "INSERT INTO [CoursesTaken] (StudentID, CourseID) VALUES ('" + TextBox1.Text + "''" + TextBox2.Text + "');";
        AccessDataSource1.InsertParameters.Add(TextBox1.Text, GridView1.Rows[newIndex].Cells[0].Text);
        AccessDataSource1.InsertParameters.Add(TextBox2.Text, GridView1.Rows[newIndex].Cells[1].Text);

        AccessDataSource1.Insert();
        AccessDataSource1.DataBind();
    }
```

And it is still giving me the error message. Would anyone mind explaining this to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a comma to separate the values like you do in your INSERT list

```
AccessDataSource1.InsertCommand = "
INSERT INTO [CoursesTaken] (StudentID, CourseID) 
VALUES ('" + TextBox1.Text + "', '" + TextBox2.Text + "');";   
AccessDataSource1.Insert();AccessDataSource1.DataBind();
```

Comment: if you used line breaks it may give you a hard time. If you didn't then I don't know what the issue could be

Comment: I don't know if it was a lag issue or what with Access but it is working now. Thank you!